# Include .js files on my Drupal site

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal-6

I want to use `jQueryUI Autocomplete` on my `Drupal` site and I downloaded the `.js` files that are needed for it to function. Now after that, I saved my `.js` files on my themes folder located at `/sites/all/themes/advanced/js`. And in my `page.tpl.php` there's this code,

```
<head>
    <?php print $head ?>
    <title><?php print $head_title ?></title>
    <?php print $styles ?>  
    <?php print $scripts ?>
    <?php print phptemplate_get_scripts(); ?>
    <?php if ($user->uid) print phptemplate_get_scripts_advanced(); ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <?php print phptemplate_get_ie_styles(); ?>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

with the code above I'm assuming that my `.js` files will be included but when I reloaded the page and check the running scripts through `Firebug`, I could not find them. What did I miss? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I did try to put my scripts manually on my `template.php` and that solved it. :)